Fetching cms page with slug url in webflow
im trying to fetch cms page with slug url inside a modal popup, and the popup modal div in homepage with embded code and this code fetches the data of threads using cms page slug url and show it inside modal popup as inner html and there's up next card in cms page to show next content ref example: https://2023.driftime.com/strategic-and-creative-partners-for-progressive-brands replicate: https://preview.webflow.com/preview/sumits-sublime-site-69cf87?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=sumits-sublime-site-69cf87&preview=877706bad27dda786ce36633ea8e51b0&workflow=preview
display the cms page inside a div inner html
